# What is the reason for this flimsy scooter engine cover?

Tags: motorcycle, design

Hello mechanics and enthusiast. My question is a bit hard to explain and visualize so I added a photo:

[image]

This is an image of Honda Beat's rear. I came upon this question while I was cleaning it this morning.

My question is, what is the purpose of this design? I mean, it makes more sense to just fully isolate the inner engine parts from mud and rain instead of having this flimsy cover as protection. Is it to cool down the engine? But most of the time mud gets to the wiring cables inside. And why a flimsy cover instead of a solid plastic mudguard?

Answer (score 2):

> What is the purpose of this design?

Judging by some other Honda Beat images online, it looks like its primary purpose is to protect the internals from the rear wheel slinging mud.

[image: Quarter Angle View]

[image: Side View]

---

> It makes more sense to just fully isolate the inner engine parts from mud and rain instead of having this flimsy cover as protection.

It does make more sense, but other factors may be at play here:

- the extra ***cost*** for such a design may not be justify the additional premium that the manufacturer would have to charge customers
- the resultant ***aesthetics*** of the scooter may not have been to someone's liking at Honda
- sealing off the engine compartment may result in ***reduced cooling***

In all likelihood, someone somewhere deemed that this flap serves as a good enough compromise.

---

> Is it to cool down the engine?

It's possible, since sealing the compartment off may result in reduced air flow.

---

> And why a flimsy cover instead of a solid plastic mudguard?

Cost.

Comment: Good points overall! Also notice that the upper portion of the drive compartment (below the flimsy cover) has a smooth finish. Its as if its intended to let mud to easily slide off.

Comment: I wouldn't read too deeply into that. Mud is mud, it doesn't slide off :)

Comment: @Zaid yes, mud sticks like s**t to a blanket...